# deletion of data older then 90 days in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Could you please suggest,  need to make procedure for cleanup data older then 90 days.

We need to create TEMP TABLE WILL HAVE records older than 90 days and STATUS SENT from J_DOC table.

```
create table TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC as select JOB_ID, last_update_time_utc, status from J_DOC where 
LAST_UPDATE_TIME_UTC <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 90 and status='Sent'; 

total records are: 4659140
select count(*) from TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC;
4659140

so we have created index on JOB_ID column to perform deletion operations faster any suggestion for faster performance:-

CREATE INDEX JOB_ID_INDEX 
ON TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC(JOB_ID);


CREATE INDEX JOB_ID_INDEX_JOB_DOC
ON J_DOC(JOB_ID);

CREATE INDEX JOB_ID_INDEX_HUB_SIG
ON HUB_SIG(JOB_ID);

we need to first delete from hub_sig table for records older than 90 days and STATUS SENT 

 delete from HUB_SIG where JOB_id IN ( SELECT JOB_ID
  FROM TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC);
  
after that we need to delete from main table J_DOC table

delete from J_DOC
 where JOB_id IN ( SELECT JOB_ID
  FROM TEMP_ID_STAT_TIME_FRM_JOB_DOC);
```

Please suggest for faster deletion operation what we can include, also once that day job is completed
we need to rename this temp table to TEMP_JOB_ID_FROM_J_DOC_1119

we need to include all these steps  in procedure , kindly suggest.

Comment: You say "faster" but do not describe any performance issue.  Have you run an explain plan on your delete statement?

Comment: How long it takes for each of the delete statement, what would you aim to achieve. Could you share explain plan?

Comment: As a bit of aside, for the usage you show - if this is a recurring operation you should be using a Global Temporary Table (GTT) for your 'temp' table.  There is no need to be repeatedly dropping and re-creating it.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - please don't advise people to use Partitioning without reminding them that is **a chargeable extra** on the Enterprise Edition. We don't want to mislead people into violating their Oracle license. (It is included free in Oracle 18c XE, but that's rarely a platform used in Production.)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the temporary table at all!

For the *other* table `HUB_SIG` use a `delete` statement that gets the `job_id` direct from the *master* table `J_DOC`using the *delete* predicate

```
delete from HUB_SIG where JOB_ID in 
(select JOB_ID from J_DOC
 where LAST_UPDATE_TIME_UTC <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 90 and status='Sent')
```

You expect an execution plan using a `HASH JOIN` and two **full tables scan**  similar to the plan below. This is the way you should approach processing large parts of tables (indexes are usefull if you process few rows!)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name    | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT    |         | 97945 |  3825K|       |   597   (1)| 00:00:08 |
|   1 |  DELETE             | HUB_SIG |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN SEMI    |         | 97945 |  3825K|  2392K|   597   (1)| 00:00:08 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| HUB_SIG | 97945 |  1243K|       |    92   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|*  4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| J_DOC   |   104K|  2767K|       |   193   (2)| 00:00:03 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("JOB_ID"="JOB_ID")
   4 - filter("STATUS"='Sent' AND "LAST_UPDATE_TIME_UTC"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)-90)
```

Delete from `J_DOC` is even simpler, user the criterium for removing rows in the `WHERE` clause

```
delete from J_DOC  
where LAST_UPDATE_TIME_UTC <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 90 and status='Sent'
```

Again no index is required, one **full table scan** will be done

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT   |       |   104K|  1434K|   193   (2)| 00:00:03 |
|   1 |  DELETE            | J_DOC |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| J_DOC |   104K|  1434K|   193   (2)| 00:00:03 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter("STATUS"='Sent' AND "LAST_UPDATE_TIME_UTC"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@
              !)-90)
```

As commented by others, of course, if you are licenced for **partitioning**, reorganize your tables use it!